# testing a radio button selection functionality

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller-extension

I am testing an updatecase method in my class which look like this:

```
 public PageReference createCase() {
  Case c = new Case(Status = 'New', Origin = 'Phone', Subject = 'This is a New Case Created',Last_Verified_by_User__c=UserInfo.getUserId(),Last_Verified_Date_Time__c = datetime.now(),ContactId = cnt.Id);
  Insert c;
  Pagereference ref = new PageReference('/' + c.Id);
  return ref;
 }
 public List<Case> excase{get;set;} // stores the list of cases in the contact
 public String radioValue{get;set;}
 public Pagereference updateCase() {
     radioValue = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('group');
     showtable=true;
     case cd = [select Id from Case where Id = : radioValue];
     cd.Last_Verified_by_User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
     cd.Last_Verified_Date_Time__c = datetime.now();
     update cd;
     Pagereference ref = new PageReference('/' + cd.Id);
     return ref;
 }
```

I get the id of the case selected using radio button in my VF page:

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!excase}" var="exscase" id="caselist" rendered="{!showtable}">
    <apex:column headervalue="Select Case">
        <input type="radio" name="group" value="{!exscase.Id}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!exscase.CaseNumber}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!exscase.Status}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!exscase.Subject}"/>
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

When i use the update function it updates two fields in the case record. I am trying to test this functionality but struck at how I can assign the value to radiovalue variable in my test class to get the case and test it. So far:

```
   @isTest
static void testupdatecase(){        
   Contact ct= new Contact (Firstname='test_firstname',LastName = 'test_lastname');
   CreateNewCase caseobject=new CreateNewCase(new ApexPages.StandardController (ct));
   insert ct;
   PageReference createref=caseobject.createCase();
   caseobject.showtable=true;
   caseobject.first=ct.FirstName;
   caseobject.last=ct.LastName;
   List<case> testcaselist=[Select Id, CaseNumber, Status, Subject from Case where contact.Name = : caseobject.first + ' ' + caseobject.last];

// CreateCase is my VF page name
    PageReference resPg=Page.CreateCase;
    system.debug('============================> Pagereference ' + resPg.getUrl());
    Test.setCurrentPageReference (new PageReference(resPg.getUrl() + '?Name=' + testcaselist[0].Id));
    resPg = caseobject.updateCase();
    System.assertEquals (resPg.getUrl(), '/' + testcaselist[0].Id);


    }
```

Comment: using a radio-type button on each row is typically handled in the controller via a wrapper class around Case that includes a Boolean `isSelected` vbl and a `Case cs` variable

Comment: @cropredy I am not sure why my this question was down voted, wondering how can I ask the SFSE community that why this questions was down voted. Any specific reason?

Comment: SfdcBat -- no idea why the downvote, - click the flag link and the moderators can assist.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't see who cast specific votes or why (that's in their head) though it does appear as if you've had a few down votes from a certain user. Chances are the system will reverse those as a case of serial down-voting. Afraid I can't do it manually!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see downvote on this question has been removed and reverted. I hope this happens for my other question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'radioValue' is reading the value from the page parameters. What you need to do is set the page parameters using `Test.setCurrentPageReference` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setCurrentPage).

All you need to do is add this line:

```
Test.setCurrentPageReference (new PageReference ('<your page URL here>?group=ct.Id'));
```

before calling `updateCase()`

Having said that, I would try to use visualforce data binding to bind the radio button to your controller's property, instead of having to go into the page parameters to find it.

Comment: I can't use a separate value for my radio value to set it in my controller since I need the id of the radio button I selected i.e excases.id

Comment: I am getting an error saying attempt to deference a null pointer exception - I added this in my test code method-        List<case> testcaselist=[Select Id, CaseNumber, Status, Subject from Case where contact.Name = : caseobject.first + ' ' + caseobject.last];
       PageReference caseref= caseobject.search();
       Test.setCurrentPageReference (caseref.getUrl() + '?group=' + testcaselist[0].Id);

Comment: Sorry , PageReference caseref= caseobject.search();  return a Null , that is why its was throwing an exception. Your line - Test.setCurrentPageReference ('<your page URL here>?group=ct.Id') , which page URL it is and how do I get it?

Comment: It should be 'apex/<your page name here>'. But it should work with almost any URL. All that matters is the query string. I would suggest editing your original question to show what your code looks like now

Comment: Can you please see the edited question. I have added a createcase() method which creates a new case and I use that page reference in my test method. But i get an error when I try to use that Url in Test.setCurrentPageReference (caseref.getUrl() + '?group=' + testcaselist[0].Id); // Error here - System.TypeException: Incompatible argument type for setCurrentPage. Maybe syntax is wrong or I am not using it correctly.

Comment: Please see my edit , I think I can use the my visualforce page name in the test class and get the page reference. And then on that page reference I can use return result of updateCase(). But I still get the incompatible error , not sure why!

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. The documentation I linked originally (you read it, didn't you?) explains clearly the type reference expected by the method. A quick glance at the page told me what the issue was :)

Comment: No Problem, Please see my updates in question after comment-    // CreateCase is my VF page name. I get "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" where I call updatecase(). The updatecase() is not getting that case id I guess. Do I need to populate the cases in public List<Case> excase{get;set;}  which is the value of radio button({!excase.id}). Or giving the Name parameter should work?

Comment: Hello, It owrked, My bad I was assign the wrong parameter "name" instead of using "group". Here -  Test.setCurrentPageReference (new PageReference(resPg.getUrl() + '?group=' + caseobject.excase[0].Id)); , this worked. Thanks for your inputs